# Rails - How to generate a single Json with these 2 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 tables, **order** and **product_orders**
they are related, in product_order it has the order_id

when I render the Json "render json: order", it comes out correct,
if I do "render json: p_order", it also outputs correct.

But I needed to generate the **order json**, with the items "quantity, unity_price and total from the Product_order table, how would I do that?
any suggestions or links for understanding/study?

```
        def call_command
          orders = Order.all
          product_orders = ProductOrder.all
  
          order = orders.map do |t|
            build = { order_id: "#{t.id}", 
                      created_at_id: "#{t.created_at}",
                      user_id: "#{t.user_id}",
                      desk_id: "#{t.desk_id}",
                      status: "#{t.status}",
                      subtotal: "#{t.subtotal}",
                      total: "#{t.total}"
                    }
          end
  
          p_order = product_orders.map do |p|
            build = { #product_order_id: "#{p.id}", 
                      # created_at_id: "#{p.created_at}",
                      order_id: "#{p.order_id}", 
                      product_it: "#{p.product_id}",
                      quantity: "#{p.quantity}",
                      unity_price: "#{p.unit_price}",
                      total: "#{p.total}"
                    }
          end
          render json: order
        end
```

Comment: Does an order have many product_orders or just one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `Order` and `ProductOrder` models are setup like this:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :product_orders
end

class ProductOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
end
```

You can use the `includes` in your `render` call, like the following:

```
@orders = Order.all
render json: @orders, include: ['product_orders']
```

You can also use the `ActiveModel` `Serializers` as @Benjamin suggested:

```
@orders.as_json(include: :product_orders)
```

Comment: More info on: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json

Comment: `.as_json` is a Rails method and has absolutely nothing to do with AMS gem.  Its actually just whats being called under the covers when you call `render json: @order`. So I don't really get where you're going with that. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json

Comment: thanks. It worked via include.